# No tests found matching Method main in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit4, powermock

My class is a test class and it has the following structure:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main");
    }

    @Test
    public void maxTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

If I press the right click on the `main` method > Run 'main', it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method main(MyClassTest) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@26aa12dd
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:35)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:41)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

If I press right click on the class name > Run 'MyClassTest.main()' it works fine printing:

```
in main
```

If I comment out `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`, everything works fine in both cases.

The same problem appears if I use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.

Why is that difference?

**Details:**

- Windows 7
- JUnit 4.12
- PowerMock 1.6.2
- Java 8
- Maven 3
- IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3

Comment: Why do you want a `main` method in Test class?

Comment: It is a temporary method. It helps me to run some static methods from the tested class and to extract the output that will be used in tests. I can create another file containing the main method, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work and how it can be fixed without avoiding the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The exception is thrown as the `main` method is not having `@Test` annotation on it.

Comment: Nice to see that you are editing some questions, but **please** also fix all other problems with the questions while you are editing. Minor edits waste the time of those having to review them, and may get rejected.

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz Taking a small step to make the site have clear questions that can be easily searched.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have a powermock required version of javassist library in your classpath.

Junit seems not able to report the correct root failure reason in this case.
For the details,you can see [this issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/1277).